# How to filter files when listing directories in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am trying to filter outout of a method, so only files with a "FF-" prefix will be returned.

My code is as follows:

```
 DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Windows\system32\tasks");
            FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.*");
            foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(file.Name);
            }
```

Comment: You know `*.*` is the same as just `*`, right?

Comment: Use Directory.GetFiles instead of directoryInfo.GetFiles if you want to handle files paths only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("FF-*.*");
```

[Directory.GetFiles Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx)

Quote:

```
* - Zero or more characters.  
? - Exactly zero or one character.
```

> For example, the searchPattern string
>   "*t" searches for all names in path
>   ending with the letter "t". The
>   searchPattern string "s*" searches for
>   all names in path beginning with the
>   letter "s".

Answer (score 1):

You can apply search pattern `"FF-*"` -or `"FF-*.txt"` for `.txt` files only-, however if want to get the **files paths only** then using `Directory.GetFiles` is better choice

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Windows\system32\tasks", "FF-*.*");

foreach (string filePath in Files)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(file.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?

```
FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("FF-*.*");
```